# BreezeJS and Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, breeze

I am new to BreezeJS and would like to know if there are any examples on how to use Breeze with an SQL Stored Procedure?

We have some pretty complex queries and want to be able to call them via an SP.  Also, how can we tell Breeze that a column returned from a SP is the Key?  We don't want to use Views, because we need to pass variables to the SP query each time we call it.

Thanks.

bob

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the basic idea would be to use Breeze's *EntityQuery.withParameters* method to pass parameters to a server side method that calls your stored proc and returns an IEnumerable. ( i.e. the result of the stored proc).

If you want to treat this result as collection of Breeze entities then you will either need to shape the results into an existing entity type that Breeze knows about from Metadata OR manually create and add a new EntityType on the client that matches the shape that you want to return.

You may want to look at the *EntityQuery.toType* method to force breeze to convert your returned data into a specific EntityType or you might alternately want to use a "*jsonResultsAdapter*" to do the same thing.

Any data that is returned from a query and is converted into an Breeze EntityType is automatically wrapped according the "modelLibrary" in use, i.e. Knockout, Angular, Backbone etc.

If breeze is not able to construct entities out of the returned data then it will still be returned but without any special processing to wrap the result.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is helpful.  I'm wondering if there are any code examples?

Comment: Sorry, not yet! But we do have a number of people who have used them successfully.

Answer (score 1):

A sample to access Sql Stored Procedures from Breeze; the store procedure (*GoStoCde*) has been imported by EF.

**Breeze Controller :**

```
 [HttpGet]
 public object GetCdes(long jprod, int jqte, long jorder)
 {
   //output params
   var owrk = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("wkres", typeof(string));
   owrk.Value = "";
   var oeror = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("ceror", typeof(int));
   oeror.Value = 0;
   //invoke stored procedure
   var envocde = _contextProvider.Context.GoStoCde(jprod, jqte, jorder, owrk, oeror);
   //stored procedure results
   var cdeResult = new {
    dwork = owrk.Value,
    deror = oeror.Value,
   };
   return new { cdeResult };
 }
```

**Datacontext :**

```
 function reqLnecde(iprod, iqte, iorder, vxeror) {
   logger.log("commande en cours...");
   var query = new EntityQuery.from("GetCdes")
        .withParameters({ jprod: iprod, jqte: iqte, jorder: iorder });
        return manager
            .executeQuery(query)
                .then(querySucceeded)
                .fail(cqueryFailed);
        function querySucceeded(data) {
                //stored procedure results
        vxeror(data.results[0]);
                //stored procedure object member value  
                keror = vxeror().cdeResult.deror;
        if (keror === 0) {
                    logger.log("commande done");
        } else {
            logger.log("article absent"); 
        }
        }
    function queryFailed(data) {
                logger.log("commande failed"); //server errors
       }
 }
```

If you prefer to return entity in lieu of object, code consequently and its must also work.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer here, just a few thoughts.
I think that the ability to return arbitrarily shaped data (read viewmodel) through the use of a stored procedure using *withParameters* would be an excellent way to inegerate with something like dapper.net. Upon resubmission of said viewmodel you could use the overloads to reconstruct actual entities out of your viewmodel and save changes. The only problem I have though is that one would need a way to easily and automaticaly rerun the sproc and send the data back to the client...
I would like to know if this makes sense to anyone else and/or if anyone has done it already.
For this sort of scenario I would think that you would need to disable the *tracking* features provided by breeze and/or write a smart enough data service that can handle the viewmodels in such a way that the javascript on the client knows when adding/removing/updating parts x,y,z of viewmodel a that you create objects jx, jy, jz (j for javascript) and submit them back and save as you go (reverse idea of what was mentioned above in a way)
Thoughts?